# Unlike other folders, dragging apps out of /Applications create an alias. What controls this behavior?

Tags: macos, finder, permission

I usually install Cyberduck by dragging the `.app` bundle into the Applications folder on the root of my hard drive (`/Applications`). However, on macOS versions 10.7 Lion and newer, if I later decide to move Cyberduck to my desktop, Finder will create an `alias` by default, instead of actually moving the `.app` bundle.

By contrast, if I instead install Cyberduck to my *user* Applications folder (`~/Applications`), and later attempt to drag Cyberduck to my desktop, the `.app` bundle will be moved like any other file.

**What makes the `/Applications` folder so special?** Is it possible to add the same behavior to another folder, or—if SIP is disabled—to modify `/Applications` to behave like a normal folder?

---

A couple things I have already tried:

1. `/Applications` is owned by `root:admin`. However, `sudo chown root:admin ~/Applications` has no effect on dragging behavior.
2. Inside of a test VM, I renamed `/Applications` to `/Applications2`. The renamed Applications2 folder retained the same dragging behavior as before, suggesting that the functionality is not hard-coded to a specific path.

Comment: Did you try creating a new folder called Applications? If so, which now gets the system icon? Best guess right now is changing its name isn't changing what may be 'special' about it [though that's simply a guess]

Comment: It is not the `/Applications` folder itself that controls this behavior per se, rather the permissions, extended attributes, ACL properties, etc. As an example, Apple apps have the `com.apple.rootless` extended attribute and `0: group:everyone deny delete` ACL properties, while non-Apples usually only have the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute. Non-Apple apps can be moved while holding down the **⌘** key while dragging.

Comment: @user3439894 How do I apply these to other folders or remove them from /Applications/? SIP is off, so it should be modifiable, right?

Comment: @Tetsujin In my macOS 10.9 VM, a renamed /Applications2 folder loses its icon despite retaining its special dragging behavior. A user-created /Applications folder does not get an icon, and has standard dragging behavior. (I re-tested to check my memory, and my previous, now-deleted comment was party wrong)

Comment: Have a look at the manual pages for `chmod` and `xattr`.

Comment: @user3439894 I know how to use both, but I don't understand what properties need to get changed! The /Applications folder does not contain any xattr. I know you said it's the apps themselves that control this, but what does that mean when the same app with the same xattr's behave differently in a normal folder than in /Applications?

Comment: Another difference with `/Applications` is its `owner:group` is `root:admin` vs. the typical `root:wheel` and has the `sunlnk` _flag_ set. I'd assume this also adds to the differences between a user created folder. Use the following command in Terminal after `cd /`, `ls -lOe@` and review the output of the various `/` (root) directories.  Also, Apple apps in /Application have the `restricted` _flag_ set as well. You can use `chown` to change the `owner:group` and `chflags` to _set/unset_ the `flags`.

Comment: People make this so hard.  /Applications is system-level, applications in it are visible to all users.  ~/Applications is not.  I can't point to anything that says so in the HIG, but it's perfectly logical that by default, moving into and out of ~/Applications is no different than any other file move, while Finder is treating /Applications specifically different to preserve other user's access to the applications.

Comment: @MarcWilson If that was what made the difference, applications copied from, say /Library would be made an alias when dragged to other folders. This is not the case. The alias behavior only happens with /Applications. In cases where the user does not have permission to write to the source directory, Finder defaults to making a copy, not an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, the premise behind this question was flawed. I originally posted this observation:

> Inside of a test VM, I renamed /Applications to /Applications2. The renamed Applications2 folder retained the same dragging behavior as before, suggesting that the functionality is not hard-coded to a specific path.

Unfortunately, this only remains true until a restart of Finder. In other words, if I rename the `/Applications` to `/Applications2`, Applications2 will retain its special dragging behavior *only until Finder is restarted!* If I `killall Finder`, Applications2 will gain normal dragging behavior.

This also works in reverse—a user-created directory moved to `/Applications` will gain special dragging behavior when Finder is restarted.

So, I think it's safe to conclude that the behavior is hard coded to specific paths, and cannot be changed. I'm disappointed, but it does make sense. I do wonder if these hardcoded Finder paths are stored in a config file somewhere that could be changed... but knowing Apple, probably not.